# Is the Stirling approximation fundamental to the derivation of the Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

In the derivations of the Boltzmann distribution I've encountered, the Stirling approximation seems to play a pivotal role. From these derivations, I've gleaned that the Stirling formula might be intrinsically linked to the emergence of the Boltzmann factor

$$ \exp \left(-{\frac {\varepsilon _{i}}{kT}}\right)$$

in statistical mechanics. Have I interpreted this correctly?

Furthermore, is there a way to derive the Boltzmann distribution without relying on the Stirling approximation?

Stirling approximation are:

$$n!\sim {\sqrt {2\pi n}}\left({\frac {n}{e}}\right)^{n}$$

or equivalently:

$$\log _{2}(n!)=n\log _{2}n-n\log _{2}e+O(\log _{2}n)$$

Comment: I derive the Boltzmann distribution in my thermodynamics class without recourse to statistical mechanics or the Stirling approximation, so no, it isn’t. But it can certainly be used in some statistical derivations.

Comment: Stirling approximation for what?

Comment: @MattHanson Can you recall the details of your derivation ? or can you post a link of such derivation ?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 there's only one approximation called Stirling approximation: the one for the factorial of large numbers.

Comment: I would be happy to share the details of my derivation once I have a moment to type it up for you.

Comment: @Ruslan, I know what Stirling approximation is. However, I cannot see the relation between the Stirling approximation for $N!$ and the Boltzmann factor as a function of energy. That was the reason for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation I use for the Boltzmann distribution only requires students to have accepted the (sort of hand-wavy) argument that the thermodynamic temperature can be reasonably defined as,
$$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial S} = T \implies \frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{T}$$
We will label a macrostates $A$ and denote the energy of the system and surroundings in this macrostate with $E_{1A}$ and $E_{2A}$, respectively and the entropies likewise. $B$ will be the label of another macrostate with the same conventions. We can make progress by exploiting the fact that the energy of the system is far smaller than the total energy or the energy of the surroundings. This lets us use the definition of a (partial) derivative to write,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E} &\approx \frac{S_2(E) - S_2(E-E_{1A})}{E_{1A}} \\
\implies S_{2A} &\approx S_2 (E-E_{1A}) = S_2 (E) - \left( \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E} \right) E_{1A} \\
\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E} &\approx \frac{S_2(E) - S_2(E-E_{1B})}{E_{1B}} \\
\implies S_{2B} &\approx S_2(E-E_{1B}) = S_2 (E) - \left( \frac{\partial S_2}{\partial E} \right) E_{1B}
\end{align*}
where we have noted that $S_{2A} = S_2 (E-E_{1A})$ and $S_{2B} = S_2 (E-E_{1B})$ are the entropy of the surroundings subject to the system having energy $E_{1A}$ and $E_{1B}$, respectively, and have used $E_{1A}$ as our "infinitesimal." Then, using the entropic definition of temperature, we obtain,
\begin{gather*}
S_{2A} = S_2 (E) - \frac{E_{1A}}{T} \\ 
S_{2B} = S_2 (E) - \frac{E_{1B}}{T}
\end{gather*}
where we have used the fact that the system and surroundings have the same temperature $T$. Finally, we note that the ratio of the probabilities of occupying two different macrostates should be the ratio of the number of different microstates that can make them up. We label the multiplicity of each macrostate as $W_A$ or $W_B$. By rearranging the Boltzmann definition of entropy, this gives,
\begin{align*}
\frac{p_A}{p_B} = \frac{W_A}{W_B} &= \frac{W_{1A} W_{2A}}{W_{1B} W_{2B}} \\ 
&= \frac{W_{1A}e^{\frac{S_{2A}}{k_B}}}{W_{1B}e^{\frac{S_{2B}}{k_B}}} \\
&= \frac{W_{1A}e^{\frac{S_2(E)}{k_B} -\frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}}}{W_{1B}e^{\frac{S_2(E)}{k_B} -\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}}} \\
&= \frac{W_{1A}e^{-\frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}}}{W_{1B}e^{-\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}}}
\end{align*}
We can use the relative ratio of probabilities for a system to occupy macrostates with energies $E_A$ and $E_B$ to find the absolute probability of occupying the state $B$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{p_A}{p_B} &= \frac{W_{1A} e^{-\frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}}}{W_{1B} e^{-\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}}} \\ 
\implies p_A &= \frac{W_{1A}}{W_{1B}} p_B e^{ - \frac{E_{1A} - E_{1B}}{k_BT}} \\ 
\implies \sum_{A} p_A &= \sum_A p_B \frac{W_{1A}}{W_{1B}} e^{ - \frac{E_{1A} - E_{1B}}{k_BT}} \\ 
\implies 1 &= \frac{p_B}{W_{1B}} e^{\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}} \sum_A e^{- \frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}} \\ 
\implies p_B &= \left[ \sum_A e^{- \frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}} \right]^{-1} W_{1B} e^{-\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}} \\
&= \frac{W_{1B}}{Z} e^{-\frac{E_{1B}}{k_BT}} \\
Z &= \sum_A W_{1A} e^{- \frac{E_{1A}}{k_BT}}
\end{align*}
where we have used the fact that the sum of the probabilities of every possible macrostate is 1, or 100%, by definition. The second to last line gives the Boltzmann factor and the final line gives the canonical partition function.

Comment: The $-1$ exponent on the last line should not be there.

Comment: Thank you for catching that error! Must have been a brain fart while looking at the previous lines.

Comment: Minor nitpick on the TeX side of things, but I've always found `\frac` inside exponents difficult to read. Far better to use either `\exp` or `/` instead of `\frac`. Alternatively in this case, you could also use $\beta=1/k_BT$ and write $\mathrm{e}^{-\beta E}$.

Comment: That’s fair,. Personally I don’t love the exp notation because it’s another notation, but the thermodynamic $\beta$ is always a good idea.

Comment: @MattHanson, thank you for the detailed answer !